# How to delete a part of a curve in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color

I would like to do this:
[image]

I am actually begin with this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
% Axis
\draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {Good 1};
\draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (0,5.5) node [above] {Good 2};
% Indifference curve
\draw (0.3,5) to   [out=280,in=175] (5.5,0.5);
\draw (0,4.1) to (4.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
For this moment, I have this.
I would like to know how delete the part of the curve under the line, and then put color of the entire intersection of both curve and line.

Comment: Welcome to TeS.SE!

Comment: That's ought to be a job for the `intersections` library

Comment: You can use `\clip` to get rid of the unwanted part of the curve.

Comment: I tried with \draw[clip] but didn't succeed.

Comment: Not really. I don't want the green part under but on the blue line.

Comment: Yes exactly like this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

I will describe my code in detail for you.

This code can be compiled at http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
unitsize(1cm);
/* page 48 (official documentation)
To make the user coordinates of picture pic represent multiples of x units in
the x direction and y units in the y direction, use
void unitsize(picture pic=currentpicture, real x, real y=x);
*/

defaultpen(linewidth(0.7bp)); // set the width of all paths by 0.7bp
/* page 41 (official documentation)
The pen line width is specified in PostScript units with pen linewidth(real). The
default line width is 0.5 bp; this value may be changed with defaultpen(pen).
*/

draw(Label("Good 1",Relative(.99)),(0,0)--(5.5,0),Arrow);
// 4.1 draw
// is equivalent to \draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {Good 1};

draw(Label("Good 2",EndPoint),(0,0)--(0,5.5),Arrow);
// is equivalent to \draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (0,5.5) node [above] {Good 2};

guide g1=(0.3,5){dir(280)}..{dir(-5)}(5.5,0.5);
// 5 Bezier curves (official documentation)
// 6.2 Paths and guides
// the direction of out=280, the direction of in = -5 ( not = 175 )

path g2=(0,4.1)--(4.1,0);
// is equivalent to \draw (0,4.1) to (4.1,0);

picture pic; // Creat a picture named pic
draw(pic,g1,red); // add g1 to pic
unfill(pic,g2--(0,0)--cycle);
/* page 18 (official documentation)
The following routine uses evenodd clipping together with the ^^ operator to unfill a
region:
void unfill(picture pic=currentpicture, path g);
*/
draw(pic,g2,blue); // g2 to pic
add(pic); // add pic to currentpicture

// Find the intersection points of two paths and then connect them.
pair[] inter=intersectionpoints(g1,g2);
draw(inter[0]--inter[1],green);

shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

There is another method using `subpath` (page 34 (official documentation)), you can do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using version 2.0 of the [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library (uploaded to CTAN in Jan 2021).  This version introduces the capability to split paths at intersection points and then extract components and splice them together.  Using that, we can split the curve and line at their crossing points and then put the correct components of each together to define the highlighted path.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569881/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, spath3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \getComponentOf \clist_item:Nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
% Axis
\draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {Good 1};
\draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (0,5.5) node [above] {Good 2};
% Indifference curve
\draw[spath/save=curve] (0.3,5) to   [out=280,in=175] (5.5,0.5);
\draw[spath/save=line] (0,4.1) to (4.1,0);
\tikzset{
  spath/split at intersections={curve}{line},
  spath/get components of={curve}\ccpts,
  spath/get components of={line}\lcpts,
}

\draw [
  line width=3pt,
  cyan,
  opacity=.5,
  spath/restore=\getComponentOf\ccpts{1}
]
[
  spath/insert=\getComponentOf\lcpts{2},
  spath/insert=\getComponentOf\ccpts{3}
];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want the different parts coloured differently then you just need to put them in different `\draw` commands.

[image: Curve and line split where they intersect]