# PGFPlots intersection segments wrong curve and endpoint

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

When trying to answer [How to delete a part of a curve in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569881/how-to-delete-a-part-of-a-curve-in-tikz) , I ran into problems with `intersection segments` from PGFPlots `fillbetween`.
I tried to change the curve from `to[out=280,in=175]` to control points, and several other thing. I always get the same result:

- red L1 seems right.
- green L2 follow the curve, but has a wrong endpoint.
- blue L3 has correct endpoints, but do not follow the curve.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=curve] (0.3,5) to[out=280,in=175, looseness=0.92] (5.5,0.5); %a curve
%\draw[name path=curve] (0.3,5) .. controls (1,1) and (2,0) .. (5.5,0.5); %alternative curve
\draw[name path=line] (0,4.1) -- (4.1,0);
\draw[red, ultra thick, opacity=0.5, smooth, intersection segments={of=curve and line, sequence={L1}}];
\pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}
\draw (\XCoord,\YCoord) circle (1pt);
\draw[green, ultra thick, opacity=0.5, smooth, intersection segments={of=curve and line, sequence={L2}}];
\pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}
\draw (\XCoord,\YCoord) circle (1pt);
\draw[blue, ultra thick, opacity=0.5, smooth, intersection segments={of=curve and line, sequence={L3}}];
\pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}
\draw (\XCoord,\YCoord) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: Curve and line with intersection segments]

Comment: I thought of this solution as well for that question and got the same result. Considering I've been having unexpected results with this library even before this, it makes me think it's just a bit buggy. It would be nice to receive an answer from the author that confirms it or not.

Comment: Anyway, I gave you a +1 because I'm curious about this as well.

Comment: I think that you are expecting too much. See https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/357.